# Must Exchange server be published on Pfsense

Tags: exchange

I have an exchange server behind a PfSence unit, internal mails are routing effectively, but external mail are not being delivered. Must i publish my server on pfsense before external mails can be delivered.

Please help, I am a rookie

Comment: **Must i publish my server on pfsense before external mails can be delivered.** - If pfsense is your firewall and is governing inbound traffic then I'd say yes, you need to publish your Exchange server in pfsense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your Exchange server on Pfsense, and you need to put through some ports such as 25, 80, 443, etc.

You could refer to: [Network ports for clients and mail flow in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deployment-ref/network-ports?view=exchserver-2019)